# How to vectorize `__call__` method

Tags: python, vector, numpy

I am following, [quant-econ](http://quant-econ.net/numpy.html) tutorial. I am trying the exercise where I am supposed to implement a [Empirical Cumulative Probability Funcion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) using vectorized numpy methods.

Here is the **correct** solution to problem:

```
class ecdf:

    def __init__(self, observations):
        self.observations = np.asarray(observations)

    def __call__(self, x): 
        return np.mean(self.observations <= x)

    def plot(self, a=None, b=None): 

        # === choose reasonable interval if [a, b] not specified === #
        if not a:
            a = self.observations.min() - self.observations.std()
        if not b:
            b = self.observations.max() + self.observations.std()

        # === generate plot === #
        x_vals = np.linspace(a, b, num=100)
        f = np.vectorize(self.__call__)
        plt.plot(x_vals, f(x_vals))
        plt.show()
```

But I am **trying** to do it this way:

```
class ecdf(object):

    def __init__(self, observations):
        self.observations = np.asarray(observations)
        self.__call__ = np.vectorize(self.__call__)

    def __call__(self, x):
        return np.mean(self.observations <= x)
```

So that, `__call__` method is vectorized and instance can be called with an array and it returns an array of cumulative probabilities for that array. However, when I try it like this:

```
p = ecdf(uniform(0,1,500))
p([0.2, 0.3])
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-6a77f18aa54e>", line 1, in <module>
    p([0.2, 0.3])

  File "D:/Users/y_arabaci-ug/Desktop/quant-econ/programs/numpy_exercises.py", line 50, in __call__
    return np.mean(self.observations <= x)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500) (2)
```

My question is, how come author could vectorize `self.__call__` and it works, while my method gives an error?

Comment: I don't know if your solution can work somehow, but I wouldn't let `__init__` (on the object side) modify the definition of the function it obtained from its own class (on the type side). IMHO, this should be done through a metaclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that way, because `__call__` must be an attribute of the class `ecdf`, not the instance. Here is my solution:

```
class ecdf(object):

    def __init__(self, observations):
        self.observations = np.asarray(observations)
        self._v_calc = np.vectorize(self._calc)

    def _calc(self, x):
        return np.mean(self.observations <= x)

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self._v_calc(x)
```